Using differentials to calculate error isn't precise
Exercise:

The radius r of a circle is measured with an error of at most 2%. What is the maximum corresponding percentage error in computing the circle’s area.

So what we know is that $\frac{dr}{r}=0.02$. Supposedly we can calculate the error in the area with calculus:
\begin{aligned}
 & A=\pi r^{2} & \\
\Longrightarrow  & dA=(2\pi r)dr & \color{blue}{absolute\ error}\\
\Longrightarrow  & \frac{dA}{A} =\frac{2\pi r}{\pi r^{2}} dr=2\frac{dr}{r}=0.04=4\% & \color{blue}{relative\ error}
\end{aligned}
But we could calculate the error in a more direct way:
\begin{aligned}
 & \frac{\Delta A}{A} =\frac{\pi ( r +\Delta r)^{2} -\pi r^{2}}{\pi r^{2}} =\frac{r^{2} +2r\Delta r\ +\Delta r^{2} -r^{2}}{r^{2}} & \\
\Longrightarrow  & \frac{\Delta A}{A} =2\frac{\Delta r}{r}+\frac{\Delta r^{2}}{r^2} & \\
\Longrightarrow  & \frac{\Delta A}{A} =0.04+0.0004=4.04\% & 
\end{aligned}
When calculating the derivative we lost its $\Delta r^{2}$ because it's supposed to be infinitesimal. But in this case it may actually be important - who knows what tolerance is acceptable in practice.
So the question then: since calculus is less precise, when does it make sense to use it for such tasks? When should we avoid it?

In practice we don't even know the error of $r$ precisely. Why is it not $2.02$%? This is a totally opinion based question that has little to do with pure maths. Rather applied maths which sometimes is an art.

Using differentials means using the best linear approximation to the function. You Unless the function starts out linear, the approximation will never be exact. The question posed is imprecise, as by "error" it means the error predicted by the linear approximation. But this abuse of language is customary in calculus books and science applications.

@TedShifrin, I see.. Got it, thanks!

The method with differentials is supposed to estimate roughly the change in function value ($\Delta A$) in terms of the change in the argument ($\Delta r$). It doesn't really give the maximum possible error in any sense, as there's no precise range of values involved. You are trying to estimate a single value, and you are certainly not doing it exactly. What you are doing is computing the error exactly, without approximation. This will always give you a closer answer than approximation, but may not be feasible to compute exactly.
